# How to display the tags?

Tags: php, wordpress, tags

I create infobook box where category as publisher and tags as genre. This is my code:

```
<table>
<?php
    $my_publisher = get_the_category();
    $my_genre = get_the_tags();

if( ! empty( $my_publisher[0] ) ) {
        echo '<tr><td align="right" class="infobook"><b>Publisher</td><td align="center" class="infobook">:</td></b><td class="infobook"> <a href="'.get_category_link($my_publisher[0]->term_id ).'">'.$my_publisher[0]->cat_name.'</a></td></tr>';
            }

if( ! empty( $my_genre ) ) {
        echo '<tr><td align="right" class="infobook"><b>Genre</td><td align="center" class="infobook">:</td></b><td class="infobook"> ' .$my_genre. ' </td></tr>';
            }
?>
</table>
```

Category as publisher is work, but tags as genre not working (do not show). 
What should I do to fix the code?

Comment: I use this code for category as publisher: <?php 
$category = get_the_category(); 
if($category[0]){
echo '<a href="'.get_category_link($category[0]->term_id ).'">'.$category[0]->cat_name.'</a>';
}
?> (source:https://dbarnwal.wordpress.com/2014/07/23/display-category-name-in-post-page/). But I have not found another way to display the tags.

Comment: I looked at the [documentation](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_tags) and it looks like it returns an array of objects so you can't just echo it like that. Look at the documentation in the link and see how they use `foreach` and get the name for each tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`get_the_tags()` returns an array of objects. Each object has a "name" property. If you want to show all the tags assigned to the post, you will have to loop through them and echo the name property of each tag. If you want to display a link for each tag, you will have to use the `get_tag_link()` function and pass in the tag object to get the link.

I modified the code; you can see it below. I am using a array to store the links and then I implode it using comma as a separator.

```
<table>
<?php
$my_publisher = get_the_category();
$my_genre = get_the_tags();

if( ! empty( $my_publisher[0] ) ) {
    echo '<tr><td align="right" class="infobook"><b>Publisher</td><td align="center" class="infobook">:</td></b><td class="infobook"> <a href="'.get_category_link($my_publisher[0]->term_id ).'">'.$my_publisher[0]->cat_name.'</a></td></tr>';
}

if( ! empty( $my_genre ) ) {
    $tag_links = array();
    foreach($my_genre as $tag) {
        $tag_links[] = '<a href="'.get_tag_link($tag).'">'.$tag->name.'</a>';
    } 
    echo '<tr><td align="right" class="infobook"><b>Genre</td><td align="center" class="infobook">:</td></b><td class="infobook"> ' . implode(',', $tag_links) . ' </td></tr>';
}
?>
</table>
```

Comment: Thank Mr.Andrew. But still not working. I'm trying to edit your code to 'if( ! empty( $my_genre ) ) {
    $tag_links = array();
    foreach($my_genre as $tag) {
    } 
    echo '<tr><td align="right" class="infobook"><b>Genre</td><td align="center" class="infobook">:</td></b><td class="infobook"> <a href="'.get_tag_link($tag).'">'.$tag->name.'</a></td></tr>';
}'. It is working, but only one tag show from 4 existing tags.

Comment: @PUSTAKAKORAN.COM oops I made a mistake in my code. I edited it. Can you try it now?

Comment: @PUSTAKAKORAN.COM don't edit it, it should work fine.

Comment: It is great..!. Thank very much Mr. Andrew. My problem is solved.